# Offset function using match function

Tags: excel

I am calculating the MAX value of (B17:M17,B22:M22) in cell L6.    I need to find the corresponding cell two rows above the MAX for the range.    I tried the formula below, but its not working.  Any ideas?

=OFFSET(MATCH(L6, (B17:M17,B22:M22),0), -2,0)

Comment: Does the match work by itself?

Comment: No.... gives a "N/A"

Comment: Then sort that, why are you expecting a result of finding L6 in a combination of two ranges? B17:M17 and B22:M22 - only works with a contiguous array. Check, correct then test that.

Comment: The MAX function is finding the max value of both ranges. (Which is what i need)   I think that's where the problem lies.   How can I find the match in two ranges?     (As an example, the first range is for day shift, the second range for night shift)

Comment: Well, it would stand a chance of working if max was in the expression but since it is absent then it stands no chance :)

Comment: So range 1 is 12am-11am   and range 2 is 12pm-11pm.    I need to find the max revenue hour (My MAX function) but then also pull the hour name (ex: 12am) which is two rows above it.

Comment: Check the function you have written and show me were max(...) is.

Comment: lol, the MAX function is in cell L6.       Then in M6 I am attempting to pull the value two rows above the max value (in L6)

Comment: L6 = MAX(B17:M17,B22:M22)      - WORKING                  M6=OFFSET(MATCH(L6, (B17:M17,B22:M22),0), -2,0)

Comment: Also match returns a number, not a range/cell. Need tow wrap it in index to get the range. But then you don't need offset, since match -2 would be your result.

Comment: @P.b think the OP may get there now.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Put the following formula in `N6`:

```
=OFFSET($B$17,ROW(IF(ISNA(MATCH(L6,$B$17:$M$17,0)),$B$22,$B$17))-ROW($B$17)-2,IFNA(MATCH(L6,$B$17:$M$17,0),MATCH(L6,$B$22:$M$22,0))-1)
```

[image]

## Explanation

As requested, here is a in-depth explanation

### Range names

I will use the following "range names" in the following explanation:

- `current_max` = $L$6 (the cell that contains the MAX formula)
- `start_range_1` = $B$17 (the first cell of the first range)
- `range_1` = $B$17:$M$17 (the first range)
- `start_range_2` = $B$22 (the first cell of the second range)
- `range_2` = $B$22:$M$22 (the second range)

## The formula

```
=OFFSET($B$17,ROW(IF(ISNA(MATCH(L6,$B$17:$M$17,0)),$B$22,$B$17))-ROW($B$17)-2,IFNA(MATCH(L6,$B$17:$M$17,0),MATCH(L6,$B$22:$M$22,0))-1)
```

Let's break it into pieces:

`=OFFSET(*anchor*, *row_offset*, *column_offset*)`

- *anchor* = `start_range_1` is the anchor / starting point of the first range.
- *row_offset* = `ROW(IF(ISNA(MATCH(current_max,range_1,0)), start_range_2, start_range_1))-ROW(start_range_1)-2`

The `IF` statements checks (with `MATCH`) whether the *current_max* is included in *range_1*. If it is not (`ISNA`), it returns the first cell of the second range (*start_range_2*), otherwise it returns the first cell of the first range (*start_range_1*). This result is wrapped in a `ROW` statement to identify the row number of that cell. As the `OFFSET` formula uses *start_range_1* as anchor, its row number is subtracted from the result. As the questioner wanted to have the result of two rows above the cell that contains the maximum value, additional 2 (rows) are subtracted.

- *column_offset* = `IFNA(MATCH(current_max,range_1,0),MATCH(current_max,range_2,0))-1`

This time, we check again, if the *current_max* belongs to *range_1*.  `MATCH` either returns the respective column or `NA`. If it returned `NA`, another `MATCH` check is initiated (via `ISNA`) to identify the column in *range_2* that featured the current maximum value. As the *anchor* is the first column, we need to subtract one column from the result.

Comment: You should really add a basic explanation in the first draft. “Teach a man to fish” and all that